# join:incompatible join fields

Tags: join

I've got two files test1.txt and test2.txt

```
sort -n -k 5 -k 6 -k 7 -t:   test1.txt
sort -n -k 5 -k 6 -k 7 -t:   test2.txt
```

There are no errors, but there is an error when I want to join both files it says that incompatible join fields 5 and 6.

```
join -e 0  -j 5 -j 6 -j 7 -t: test1.txt test2.txt >test
# join: incompatible join fields 5, 6
```

The examples of contexts are just like this:

Text1.txt

```
chr2    120683995       120684016       STE00144:391:H7V5MALXX:2:1101:2473:9818        25      +
```

Text2.txt

```
chr2    150021705       150021726       STE00144:391:H7V5MALXX:3:1101:2544:23513       25      -
```

I want to join two files by the same context of field 4.

Comment: Can you give an example of `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`?

Comment: ok, I just saw it before.

Comment: Please [edit] them in rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: I don't think `join` can take more than one field to join on, you have three fields listed on the command line `-j 5 -j 6 -j 7`

Comment: I agree with @ilkkachu. Only one `-j` option should be given. But both your sort command and your join command indicate that you want to include columns 5,6 and 7 while you state that you want to join the files by the field **4**. Please remove the contradiction from your question and state clearly what you want to do. Thanks

Comment: though with the `-t:`, perhaps you want to join based on some colon-separated fields of column 4, but I do wonder what the output would be expected to look in that case. Of course with the two sample lines, the colon-separated columns 6 and 7 are different, so joining on them wouldn't do anything...

Comment: In the end, I found the problem is that join can't take more than one field to join on.I used awk solved my problem,thank u all.